# Groovy constructors

Tags: groovy, constructor

I'm having a problem while using constructors with a Groovy class.

I have a class `Data` in a file called `Data.groovy` with an inner class `ContentEntry`. I want to initialize `ContentEntry` instances from a `Data` method:

```
static void initContent(nid, uid)
{
    curContent = new ContentEntry()
    curContent.nid = nid;
    curContent.uid = uid;
}
```

with `ContentEntry` defined as:

```
class ContentEntry
{
    public int nid, uid 
    private tags = [:]

    public ContentEntry()
    {

    }

    ContentEntry(int nid, int uid)
    {
        this.nid = nid
        this.uid = uid
    }

    //omitted rest of the class
```

But when running the project it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodSelectionException:
Could not find which method <init>() to invoke from this list:
public it.softit.Data$ContentEntry#<init>(it.softit.Data, int, int)
public it.softit.Data$ContentEntry#<init>(it.softit.Data)
```

It's like if constructors implicitly need an instance of the outer class passed as a parameter. I'm wondering why..

Comment: 3 food anwers thanks, upvoted all of you.. In 6 years of Java programming never knew this thing about implicit reference. I fixed it declaring them as normal classes since you cannot declare them static in groovy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The requirement that all (non-static) inner classes need a reference to their outer class is imposed by Java, rather than Groovy. If you instantiate the inner class from a non-static method, the reference should be set to `this`. However, there is no `this` reference within a static method.

To fix the problem either:

- Instantiate the inner class from a non-static method
- Make the inner class static. Then you can instantiate it from anywhere (but it will no longer have a reference to an instance of the outer class).

Answer (score 4):

Of course the constructor need a instance of the outer class. That's why inner class exist: to live only within an outer class. You cannot instanciate an inner class outside of its outer class.

Comment: It's important to note that Java and Groovy act differently here: In Java the outer class instance is passed in implicitly, while in Groovy you need to pass it as an explicit argument!

Comment: To add to what gizmo said, making the content class `static` might be helpful too.

Comment: @Joachim: when I try to do that, it tells me: no such constructor (also, hasn't this been fixed in 1.7.1?)

Answer (score 2):

In Java happens the same, but when you instantiate an inner instance you don't have to include the hidden parameter.

Try one of two things:

1. declaring the inner class static (I
   hope you can do that in Groovy too)
2. passing `this` in the creation of
   the `ContentEntry` instance... :)